# How do you access the jQuery object ($) in an entry file when using Webpack 4?

Tags: jquery, webpack-4

I have a very simple Webpack 4 example where I am trying to access the jQuery object in my entry file in order to manipulate the DOM.  I have pared it down to what I think is the bare minimum having researched extensively.

I expect the example to set the background color of the `body` to cyan upon page load. Can't seem to get it to do anything.  Looks like the `$` variable exposed in the entry file is **not** the same `$` variable in the browser.

**UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED**:  I was misusing `jQuery` below.

**Original** (defective) entry file (`src/app.js`):

```
import 'jquery';

$(() => {
  $('body').bgColor = 'cyan';
});
```

**Corrected** entry file:

```
import 'jquery';

$(() => {
  $('body').css('background-color', 'cyan');
});
```

I use the `ProvidePlugin` as documented [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/).  Here is my simple `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
  },
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
}
```

Webpack compiles just fine and the page opens (using `webpack-dev-server`), but the background color does not change to cyan as expected. When I log the value of `$('body')` in the `app.js` file, I get `undefined`.

Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Feels like I have a fundamental lack of understanding of how this is supposed to work.  Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: jQuery object has no `bgColor` property that would affect the element. Use `css()` method or access the native element `$('body')[0]`

Comment: Yes @charlietfl, thank you.  My bad.  Changed the jQuery call to use the `css()` function and all is well.  Silver lining - there's a simple example that others can use.  I'll post the answer and put this code somewhere in Github.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies.  My mistake on misuse of jQuery.  Thanks to @charlietfl for pointing out my mistake in the comments. I used. `$('body').bgColor = "cyan"` instead of `$('body').css('background-color', 'cyan')`. Everything else is properly configured.  So if you need a simple example, here it is.

I will edit the question and point out my mistake.